# replace sub query with join

Tags: sql, join, subquery, informix

I have the following query:

```
select distinct dco datpos 
from bkhis 
where dco>=(select min(dco) 
            from bkhis 
            where dag=TODAY - 1 and dco<=dag)
```

Due to the Informix version we use (10.00), we can't work with sub query and with the aggregation function in the sub query it become more complicated.

Can anyone help me please to rewrite this query using join.

Comment: What version are you using ?

Comment: Please give an outline schema of the table.  Are `dco` and `dag` both of type `DATE`?  Or some other type?  Please show some sample data and the expected results for that data.  You'd probably need to replace `TODAY - 1` with some fixed date (use `MDY(4,27,2018)` notation) so that the query will work on the sample data in the future.

Comment: I can't think of a version of Informix that would not support that sub-query — I think even the prehistoric versions from before 1990 would handle the sub-query.

Comment: i m using informix 10 that does not support embedded request.

Comment: Time to upgrade!  Several years ago.  And what error do you get?  And please add the outline schema and sample data.

Comment: 'dco' and 'dag' are both of type 'DATE'

Comment: Edit the question.  Add the information — about version, outline schema, sample data, expected result, and error message — to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no comma between `dco` and `datpos` in your question here: `... distinct dco datpos`; I am assuming that this is a typo.

Use this query:

```
select distinct b.dco, b.datpos 
from bkhis b
JOIN bkhis b1 ON b.dco >= b1.dco
WHERE b1.dag=TODAY - 1 and b1.dco<=dag
```